# Unable to access dynamically created Javascript div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simplified version of my code.  I am guessing I am not creating iDiv correctly because this line   `$('#iDiv').click(function(){`    is never happening.

Not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any suggestions to try.

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('buttonx').click(function(){
        createiDiv();
    });

    //this works great:
    $('#iframeWrapper').click(function(){   
        var localiDiv = document.getElementById("iframeWrapper");
        localiDiv.style.backgroundColor = "aqua"; 
    });

    // but iDiv is not recognized here and I can't figure out why   
    $('#iDiv').click(function(){    
        var localiDiv = document.getElementById("iframeWrapper");
        localiDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime"; 
    });
});

function createiDiv(){
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var iframeWrapper = document.getElementById ('iframeWrapper');
    iDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    iDiv.id = 'iDivID'; - made change so this is = 'iDiv'
    iDiv.style.width = "600px";
    iDiv.style.height = "400px";
    iframeWrapper.appendChild(iDiv);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="iframeWrapper"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: where do you even call `createiDiv()`?

Comment: I cleaned up too much code.  Under $(document).ready I have a button that calls CreateiDiv()  I know this works as I can see it but I can't click on iDiv to do other stuff

Comment: Aside from the ID mismatch, you can only bind the event handler once the element exists. Or use event delegation. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I will read on this - thank you.  I fixed up the ID but it still does not work.

Comment: @user3105748: Probably because of what I mentioned in my comment ;)

Comment: Felix - yes, moving the $('#iDiv').click(function() to the end of the create function did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the element's id to the same value you then try to use in the jQuery selector:

```
iDiv.id = 'iDivID';
```

Should be

```
iDiv.id = 'iDiv';
```

Otherwise

```
$('#iDiv').click();
```

cannot work because a jQuery selector using `$('#iDiv')` explicitly looks for a `DIV` element with an `id` of `iDiv` (and not `iDivID`)

Of course, as another user mentioned in a comment, you need to actually call your `createiDiv()` function in order for the code within the function to be executed, by i assume you already know (and do) that (somewhere in code you have not posted).

Also you should incorporate the click handler **after** the element is created, not before. (I did not notice this mistake - user *Felix Kling* suggested it)

**Hint**

Since you're already using jQuery, you can optimize your code a bit so that it is more compact.

For instance you could change:

```
iDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
iDiv.style.width = "600px";
iDiv.style.height = "400px";
```

to:

```
$('#iDiv').css({
    'background-color': 'lime',
    'width': 600,
    'height': 600
});
```

Please note that unless you use an already reserved name for a variable, you don't have to put the keys (`width`, `height`, etc.) in quotes. You could also use `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color` as jQuery understands both. Bear in mind though that if you use the hyphen `-` in a key, you should place the key in quotes.

**UPDATE**

Here is some example on how you could apply the click handler after the element is generated:

```
function createiDiv(){
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var iframeWrapper = document.getElementById('iframeWrapper');
    iDiv.id = 'iDiv';
    iDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    iDiv.style.width = "600px";
    iDiv.style.height = "400px";
    iframeWrapper.appendChild(iDiv);
    $(iDiv).click(function(){
        var localiDiv = document.getElementById("iframeWrapper");
        localiDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime"; 
    }); // please note that you can use the DOM element `iDiv` in the jQuery selector (you don't have to use the ID if you have the actual element referenced in a variable)
}
```

And here is an example of the same function, but optimized for jQuery entirely:

```
function createiDiv(){
    $('<div/>')
      .attr('id', 'iDiv')
      .css({
          'background-color': 'lime',
          'width': 600,
          'height': 600
      })
      .click(function(){
          $('#iframeWrapper').css('background-color', 'lime');
      })
      .appendTo('#iframeWrapper');
}
```

Comment: I am doing this - I create the div via createiDiv in document.ready and do not try to click on this div until it is displayed.  I will see if I can edit my initial code to make it clearer

Comment: I don't see an element with class `buttonx` in your HTML structure.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.  I especially appreciate the optimized version so I can learn how I should be coding.  I will copy and play with this now.

Answer (score 0):

You have your IDs different:

```
iDiv.id = 'iDivID';

$('#iDiv').click(function(){
```

one is iDivID and one is iDiv, make sure these are both the same.

You set the id to "iDivID" in the first line.
In the second line, you're trying to access it via CSS selector refering to an element who has the ID "iDiv"

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the `createiDiv()` function is never called.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //this works great:
    $('#iframeWrapper').click(function () {
        var localiDiv = document.getElementById("iframeWrapper");
        localiDiv.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    });

    //create iDiv
    createiDiv();

    // but iDiv is not recognized here and I can't figure out why   
    $('#iDiv').click(function () {
        var localiDiv = document.getElementById("iframeWrapper");
        localiDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    });
});

function createiDiv() {
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var iframeWrapper = document.getElementById('iframeWrapper');
    iDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    iDiv.id = 'iDivID';
    iDiv.style.width = "600px";
    iDiv.style.height = "400px";
    iframeWrapper.appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/ZRB2T/

Answer (score 0):

For assigning events to elements added dynamically use event delegation for example

instead of

```
$('#iframeWrapper').click(function(){
```

use

```
$('#iframeWrapper').on('click', function(){
```

refer

[Jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)